# Is there a way in Ruby to set values of members of class using public_methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to set value of members of class using `public_methods` list. But in the code given below "className.member" will not work as ".member" is not member of `ClassName` class.

Is there any way in ruby to set value of members in such a way?

The code below:

```
  membersArray = className.public_methods
  membersArray.each {|x|
      member = x.to_s
      className.member = "some value"
    end

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foo.bar = 1
```

This line is, essentially, an invocation of method `bar=` with argument `1`.

```
foo.bar=(1)
```

You can call methods dynamically using `send` method

```
foo.send "bar=", 1
```

So, your code shall be rewritten as

```
className.send "#{x}=", 'some value'
```